# Strange Flex Sizing in IE on Server2003

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internet-explorer, windows-server-2003, size

I have a modified version of a flex calendar found [Here](http://www.chadupton.com/blog/2009/02/flex-calendar-component/), and though it looks alright on most computers I've seen, there is a problem on two of the three servers here. Because of the way Citrix is setup here, I need to have it functional on all of the servers.

When it loads, everything is stretched out vertically, and the numbers are missing on the date boxes. If you mouse-over the flex buttons, they jump to the right size, but there is still rendering errors.

The modifications I made had no effect, because the servers give the same results on both my version and the demo version hosted online. As far as I can tell, the servers are identical (IE version, Flash version, etc.)

How can I get it to display normally?

[Initial View](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/268f85d615.png)

[After Mouseover](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/05dbb63378.png)

[Usual Demo](http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/calendar/app.html)

[Demo in bad server](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/052ff5e406.png)

Edit: On the server that renders it improperly, Firefox renders it fine, but Firefox cannot be used for other (unchangeable) reasons.

Answer (score 0):

From the images it appears this is how the SWF appears in the Browser of each server - one good and one bad. Not how the SWF appears in any browser while being hosted from each server.

Sense it is the browser display that is not working correctly I would assume it is a rendering problem with the browser and not the server.

1.) The problem could come from JavaScript being disabled in one of the browsers and the view being taken from the  embed tag. Check to ensure that it looks the same with JavaScript both on and off.

2.) The height being 100% could also be messing it up in the browser. Try setting the height to a specific value (800px) and see if that corrects the problem.

3.) Make sure that the browsers are the same. Is one IE 7 and one IE 8? If they are the same, check the version number to ensure that all updates are the same for each.

4.) View the site from another computer that is connected to the server.

Number 1 and 2 would be my best guess as a way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Discounting both 1 and 2 I used the example flash embed code from W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp and it worked once again in only one of the three servers. The bowers are both the latest version of IE, and it also works in that version on my computer. Number 4 also works fine. Firefox renders it well on the server, but we cannot use Firefox on the servers for other reasons.

Comment: Why does it matter how it appears on the server? If it works on the client then that is all that matters, correct?

Comment: The way Citrix is setup here, each user gets a session on the server, so they use the servers applications. This is scheduled to change in the future, but for the moment the user gets the servers IE, and it would appear broken. As a workaround we are publishing IE from a fourth server (as to not put too much load on the three main servers),which defaults to my calendar application. This is suboptimal because the user then has two sessions instead of one, among other things.This is for employees, and because it chooses servers randomly,currently the application is formatted strange 2/3 sessions